# I didn't rename but EF is giving me a multiple identity column error

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So I have this table that is already populated and built with EF

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    //ForeignKey from SubCats table
    public int? SubCatId { get; set; }
    public SubCat SubCat { get; set; }

    public byte? Image { get; set; }

    public int PointId { get; set; }
    public int Points { get; set; }
}
```

Anyways, I connected my database with sql server management studio and EF gave me an error that all my migrations are pending even though i already updated the database with each migration but i guess it has something to do with sql server management studio! so i tried to run update-database again and it gave me this error:

Multiple identity columns specified for table 'Items'. Only one identity column per table is allowed.

I searched for it and all the answers were about renaming the key column but the problem is i didn't rename anything! please give me a solution to this problem
p.s I am new to this so please keep your answers simple so I can understand

Comment: Look at your `PointId` and `Points`. Is `PointId` is the foreign key of `Points`? Please clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the primary key and foreign keys of the `Item` explicitly  as follows:

```
public class Item
{
     [Key]
     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Description { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("SubCat")]
     public int? SubCatId { get; set; }
     public SubCat SubCat { get; set; }

     public byte? Image { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("Point")]
     public int PointId { get; set; }
     public Point Point { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.